# Is Azure Management Library deprecated in favor of Azure Resource Manager?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

For Azure automation we used [Management Libraries](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries) in order to provision Cloud Services & BLOB Storage along with SQL Database. This seem to be no longer maintained. Shall we stop using this in production? 
Need to provision:

Azure Web APP

SQL Database

BLOB

Azure Search Index

Any authoritative information on the recommended approach now, would be much helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may already know `Azure Management Library` is a wrapper over `Azure Service Management API (ASM)` which provided a REST based interface to manage the underlying infrastructure. Old Azure Portal (https://management.azure.com) makes use of ASM API.

`Azure Resource Manager API (ARM)` is the new REST based intefface to manage underlying infrastructure. ARM is more robust, feature rich and will be used going forward. New Azure Portal (https://portal.azure.com) makes use of ARM API.

Eventually old portal will be removed and you should be able to do all the things on the new portal. When that will happen is not generally known (someone from  Azure product team will be able to comment on that). Until then, both ASM and ARM will be supported and after that ASM will be removed (or not supported).

General recommendation would be to start using ARM API wherever possible. Only use ASM API for the features that have not been ported to ARM API. You mentioned that you are using Azure Web APP, SQL Database, BLOB, and Azure Search Index. To the best of my knowledge, all of these are supported in ARM so the recommendation would be to use that instead of ASM. In fact, I think Azure Search is only supported via ARM and not ASM.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any information on which the currently advised library to use is.

However, a few weeks ago [Simpler Azure Management Libraries for .NET](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/simpler-azure-management-libraries-for-net/) was released into preview. It might be worth checking it out and keeping an eye on it for the future.

At the moment it seems only capable of managing Azure Virtual Machines, Virtual Machine Scale Sets, Storage, Networking, Resource Manager, Key Vault and Batch. However, since this is a preview, MS is asking developers to provide feedback and what they would like to see support next.